# Effects of AI based education in mathematics in PISA like studies

Tags: reference-request, technology-in-education, pisa

One of the biggest revolutions in education in the last few years seems to be the use of artificial intelligence to offer adaptive individualized learning environments as done by companies like [squirrel](http://squirrelai.com/), [knewton](https://www.knewton.com/) or [aleks](https://www.aleks.com/).

Are the [PISA](https://www.oecd.org/pisa/) data detailed enough to measure effects by such AI based approaches in mathematics? If so, was this point investigated and what are the results?

Comment: AI is hype. I know this to be true because my computer told me.

Comment: :-) At least it is advertised as a revolution. I am indeed not a fan of AI based education, but I don't have much objective arguments against it.

Comment: I'll echo that *a lot* of products adopt the "AI" label for marketing and are hyped. AI is a broad descriptor, so I'm not sure that even if data were available that any strong conclusions could be made. I think that some machine learning tools could be useful for K-12 mathematics, particularly for determining/analyzing the connectedness of standards.

Comment: Anything remotely close to AI are automatic driving or flying systems. Everything else is just pattern analysis. "Adaptive individualized learning" in the form "if you can do this, do that" have existed for at least half a century. Nothing new so far. You may want to watch 1980s TV shows hyping computerized education.

Comment: @Ivana: What software does the school of your kids use? What do you and your kids think about it?

Comment: The promise of "individualized learning environments" goes back to at least [PLATO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PLATO_%28computer_system%29) software in the 1960's, or [correspondence courses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_education) in the 1800's, or [mass-produced books](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johannes_Gutenberg) in the 1400's.

Comment: @student Pluspunt form Malmberg (Netherlands), the underlying framework is Bingel wich uses Knewton knowledge maps. Its more or less ok: looks good, clear feedback of what the child has learned according to the system, keeps stats on how long the assignments took. The big problem, IMHO, is that the teacher neither knows or can change the assignments the child has. 90% of all assignments is individualized, so teacher cannot keep up with all the kids. If there is a question she tells them they have to figure it out themselves.

Comment: @student  If the math is too difficult or too easy, we wouldn't know except for homeschooling due to corona. And when the math is too easy or to difficult (in some weeks both are the case: addition under 10 and really hard questions with permutations) there is nothing to be done. Technically the teacher can change a part of the assignments (only part) but they cannot realistically do this for each child each week.

Answer (score 2):

In an attempt to answer your question:

> Are the PISA data detailed enough to measure effects by such AI based approaches in mathematics?

I found three things that point to the answer being **no**.

1. I dug through the [2018 PISA School Questionnaire](https://www.oecd.org/pisa/data/2018database/CY7_201710_QST_MS_SCQ_NoNotes_final.pdf), which is administered to school principals, and found no question on AI that would allow the data to be parsed in this way. I only searched this questionnaire, so it's possible the question comes up elsewhere, but I would be surprised if it was. (For reference, the full list of master questionnaires from 2018 can be found [here](https://www.oecd.org/pisa/data/2018database/#d.en.516012).)
2. A draft of the [2021 PISA framework](https://pisa2021-maths.oecd.org/files/PISA%202021%20Mathematics%20Framework%20Draft.pdf) has lots of mentions of Computer-Based Assessments of Mathematics (CBAM) and computer simulations, but no reference to Artificial Intelligence (AI) that I can find. The draft I found was from November 2018 though, so its entirely possible that something has been added to address this, but (again) I would be surprised if it was.
3. My third point is anecdotal, but perhaps valuable, and it echoes the early comments to the original post. In the not so recent past (but still less than 10 years ago) I was teaching a college remedial mathematics course at an institution in the New York City area that was using an "Artificial Intelligence"-esque system for students to complete modules of work. The company that we used sought feedback on the system and provided cash incentives for educators who found mistakes in their software (either mistakes, typos, or sequencing), which gave me the feeling that these billed "Artificial Intelligence" learning environments are in actuality just logic trees that software engineers and mathematics educators have built out by brute force. Now, it has been some time since I have taught with this software, but I have seen nothing in the interim to suggest that the AI software you're referring to is anything but "hype".

Comment: Thanks. About your anecdotal point: Do you remember what software your institution used at that time? Do you know if it is used today? Or did they stop using this system or do they use a successor system?

Comment: It was called Hawkes Learning, and I don't know if they still use it, or some other program.